# create working link to high-scores page in CakePhp 2.9

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working with CakePHP 2.9 on a math-quiz application. My status with CakePHP is 'beginner'.

I would like to create a link to a high-scores page in app/Layouts/default.ctp. 
Therefore, I edited the default link to the CakePHp website into

`<li><a target="_blank" href=".<?php $this->Getscores->getscores();?>.">High scores</a></li>`.

But as far as now, the only thing I observe when clicking the link is a redirection to the landing page, no stack trace or error messages available.

This is what I have done as sofar:

1. Create a controller named `GetscoresController.php` in the directory `app/Controller/`
2. Set class name in `GetscoresController.php` to `GetscoresController`
3. Created a public function `getscores()` inside the class `GetscoresController`
   To reduce complexity I only create a variable `$myvar` assigned to the value "hiscores" in this function:

   `$myvar='hiscores';
   $this->set(compact('myvar');`
4. Created a getscores.ctp in app/View/Getscores/ with only the code 
   `<?php echo $this->myvar; ?>`
5. Created an extra route in app/Config/routes.php:
   `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'getscores', 'action' => 'index', 'getscores'));`

I am wondering why the steps I took, obviously were not satisfying to get the link working.
Can anyone point me out what I have done wrong and help me to set the link correct?

Comment: It's not working because you've tried to use the output of your `getscores` function as the URL to link to. That's a basic PHP misunderstanding, not a CakePHP thing. @Salines answer is the way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using html helper?

```
<li>
   <?= $this->Html->link('High scores', [
      'controller'=> 'Getscores', 
      'action' => 'getscores',
      $myvar // <-------------------
      ], 
      ['_target' => 'blank'] ); ?> 
</li>
```